# How is a Tor hidden service mapped to the 80 bit hash of the service's public key?

Tags: onion-services

How does the name of a Tor hidden service (zzzz.onion) encode the 80 bit hash mentioned below?

```
"permanent-id" is the permanent identifier of the hidden service,
consisting of 80 bits. It can be calculated by computing the hash value
of the public hidden service key and truncating after the first 80 bits:

   permanent-id = H(public-key)[:10]
```

[Source.](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec.txt#n234)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I'm answering the right question, but:

```
onion_address = base32(permanent_id) || ".onion",
```

Where base32 is base32 encoding.
Source: [Efficient botnet herding within the Tor network](https://lachlankang.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/descriptors.pdf)